# Alinear a la derecha e izquierda dentro de un flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Lo que intento hacer es algo sencillo, lo hice muchas veces pero les juro que llevo trabado mas de una hora.

Tengo un `carrousel` y lo que quiero es alinear los iconos `left rigth` en sus respectivos lugares, osea derecha e izquierda, pero no logro hacerlo...

```
<div class="carrousel" id="carrousel_grid">
    <div class="atras botones"><i class="far fa-angle-left"></i></div>
    <div class="adelante botones"><i class="far fa-angle-right"></i></div>
</div>


CSS

.carrousel {
grid-area: carrousel;
background: url("../img/carousel/moutains_home.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
transition: .6s;
width: 100%;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
}

.carrousel .atras {
font-size: 35px;
}

.carrousel .adelante {
font-size: 35px;
}
```

Ayuda... logro que esten centrados verticalmente, pero no se como mandar el `rigth` a la derecha. Por si preguntan, todo el carrousel esta hecho con JS, no es relevante pero, por si acaso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo general se ponen como position: absolute referentes al contenedor padre (carousel debe ir relative. Luego los posicionas con top left a gusto, ej el izq top 50% left 5% y el derecho top 50% left 95%

Answer (score 0):

Bien, eso es sencillo de realizar.

El contenedor padre, `carrousel` debe ser posición relativo, y debe tener una altura fijo (al menos que el slide, el contenedor de las imágenes tenga su altura). Con estos dos definidos ya se puede trabajar como quieres con los `botones`.

Ahora, a los hijos, que yo hago uso de los `botones` para mejorar, de ser de posición absoluta. Esto para que quede encima de todos los demás hermanos (que sería el slide contenedor de las imágenes). Por eso el padre debe ser de posición relativo.

Para acomodar, es mejor que sea `top:0`, `width:50px` (o lo que guste) y `height:100%`.

Luego de esto se usa independientemente `atras` y `adelante` para ubicarlos con sus respectivos lados: **`left`** y **`right`**.

Para una mejor optimización, cambie de lado las clases *botones* y *adelante*, porque el primero, *botones* tiene más clases declarados; mientras que el siguiente es secundario, pero importante.

Ahora el ejemplo completo:

```css
.carrousel { 
 grid-area: carrousel; 
 background: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature");
 background-position: center; 
 background-size: cover; 
 transition: .6s; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px; /* para el demo */
 display:flex; 
 align-items: center; 
 position: relative;
} 

.carrousel .botones {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 top: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(128,0,0, .5)
}

.carrousel .atras { 
 left: 0;
} 

.carrousel .adelante { 
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carrousel" id="carrousel_grid"> 
 
 <div class="botones atras">
  <i class="far fa-angle-left">←</i>
 </div> 
 
 <div class="botones adelante">
  <i class="far fa-angle-right">→</i>
 </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: No olvides marcar ✓ si te sirvió la respuesta, para que ayude a otros con el mismo problema.